# Wordpress : Get assigned data value from defined variables

Tags: wordpress

I am working in an e-commerce site built with WordPress. I want to assign a zip code to each city in the country as users tend to misspell the names.

So I want it in a way that each time the type a city it's zip code appears.

Example when i type in New York I should have 00012 pop up.

Any suggestion would be welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used one plugin please follow this plugin this will help to get zip code you need to do bit custom design if you need

here is link https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-locator/

Their parent demo is here: https://locatewp.com/